# Doing the following operations in Azure ML Studio through REST calls

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is there any possibility of doing the following operations in Azure ML Studio through REST calls?
1) Create and upload a new dataset.
2) Create a new Automated ML run selecting an already created dataset, configuring the experiment name, target column and training cluster and selecting the task type (e.g. Classification/Regression).
3) Deploy the run on a container and retrieve the container endpoint URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the APIs available at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/ 
 for Azure ML studio through REST API calls, but other than dataset-related API.

[image]